# Central extensions of SL2(R) by U(1) ?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-k-theory

Can somebody please tell me what are the central extensions of SL2(R) by U(1), that is, what is $H^2(SL2(R), U(1)) $ ? Thank you

Comment: If you are considering $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ as a discrete group, the answer is rather complicated, see [this question](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/63529/universal-cover-of-sl2r-does-it-admit-central-extensions) and the various answers. On the other hand if you are considering $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ as a Lie group, then any central extension is the pushforward of the universal cover by some homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathrm{U}(1)$; this follows easily from the fact that every central extension of $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is trivial.

Comment: Just a technical comment that you should use LaTeX for mathematical symbols, to avoid ambiguity.   For instance, your symbol R might just mean a ring in the context of algebraic K-theory, or might mean the field $\mathbb{R}$ of real numbers.