# What is known about the discrete group cohomology $H^2(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C), \mathbb C^\times)$?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, lie-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology, group-cohomology

The cohomology ring of $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb C)$ as a *topological* group is straightforward (it's generated by a Chern class), but what is known in the discrete case? I'm particularly interested in $H^2$ with coefficients in $\mathbb C^\times = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}$, especially if there are explicit formulas for the classes.

Comment: As a discrete group $H_2(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{C}))$ has continuum cardinal. Probably this is still true modulo torsion. If so, this $H^2$ is huge (maybe even of cardinal power of the continuum). A full description possibly exists in terms of Kähler differentials. Related: https://mathoverflow.net/a/63599/14094

Comment: I think with Matsumoto's theorem, you can identify $H_2(SL_2(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Z})$ with $K^M_2(\mathbb{C})$, and then you could use universal coefficient formulas to get statements about second cohomology with $\mathbb{C}^\times$-coefficients. Not sure if this is specific enough, but the torsion should be controllable, the uniquely divisible part less so.

Comment: As a follow-up on the link to Milnor K-theory, elements of $H^2({\rm SL}_2(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{C}^\times)$ should be given by $\mathbb{C}^\times$-valued Steinberg coycles. Those are maps $\mathbb{C}^\times\times\mathbb{C}^\times\to \mathbb{C}^\times:(u,v)\mapsto \{u,v\}$ which are bimultiplicative and satisfy $\{a,1-a\}=1$. That point of view may help with computations, the K-book has more information in this direction in the $K_2$-section.

Comment: Thanks! I know very little about K-theory, so your suggested point of view is helpful.

Answer (score 8):

There is a paper by Milnor called [On the homology of Lie groups made discrete](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ev1ranick/papers/milnor7.pdf) which contains many results on this kind of problem, as well as references to related literature.  However, I don't think that it directly answers your question.

Comment: Could you please add some information on the state of art of the Milner conjecture (which I presume is made in this paper) to your answer?!

Comment: I don't know the current status. I am not an expert in this area, I merely reported something that I remembered reading a long time ago.

Comment: MathSciNet will give you a list of all the papers that cite the one that I mentioned, and that will presumably include all papers that make progress on the conjecture.