# Schur multiplier of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, schur-multipliers

What is the Schur multiplier of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Q})$? The techniques used [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63529/universal-cover-of-sl2r-admits-no-central-extensions/63554#63554) give $K_2(\mathbb{Q})$ as a lower bound, but it’s probably bigger than that, especially since the universal cover of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ should restrict to a stem extension by $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $H_2(SL_2(F))$ is isomorphic to $K_2(F)$ for every field $F$. An explicit calculation can be found eg. in Matsumoto's paper 'Sur les sous-groupes arithmetiques des groupes semi-simples deployes'.

Comment: @Linus so Wikipedia is wrong when it claims that K_2(F) is trivial for all finite F?

Comment: @DanielSebald could you provide some context? what do you know about $H_2(\mathrm{SL}_2(F))$ for finite fields $F$?

Comment: I have to correct my comment, $H_2(SL_2(F))$ is isomorphic to symplectic $K$-theory $KSp_2(F)$, as Matsumoto shows. In characteristic different from 2 there is a short exact sequence $1 \to I^3F \to KSp_2(F) \to K_2(F) \to  1$. Here $IF$ is the fundamental ideal in the Witt ring.

Comment: @Linus you might write an answer then?

Comment: @YCor $H_2(\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_q))$ is nontrivial if q=4 or q=9.

Answer (score 3):

$\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\Sp{Sp}$For a field $F$ with $|F|>4$ and $|F|\neq9$, the group $H_2(\SL_2(F))$ has a presentation in terms of the symplectic Steinberg symbols;
that is, $H_2(SL_2(F))\cong KSp_2(F)$. This is shown for infinite fields in Matsumoto's paper [M], Cor. 5.11., and in general in Steinberg's Yale lecture notes [St] p. 78.

For fields of characteristic different from 2, there is a short exact sequence
$$1 \to I^3F \to K\Sp_2(F) \to K_2(F)\to 1.$$
Here $IF$ is the fundamental ideal in the Witt ring $WF$. The group $K\Sp_2(F)$ is trivial if $F$ is a finite field. For this, see Hahn-O'Meara's book [HO] p. 379.

References:

[HO] A. Hahn, Alexander, T. O'Meara.
The classical groups and K-theory. Springer-Verlag, 1989.

[M] H. Matsumoto 'Sur les sous-groupes arithmétiques des groupes semi-simples déployés', Annales Sci. ENS 1969. [DOI link](https://doi.org/10.24033/asens.1174) (Numdam unrestricted access)

[St] R. Steinberg, Lectures on Chevalley Groups, Yale 1967

Comment: But does this answer the question what is $H_2({\rm SL}_2({\mathbb Q}))$?

Comment: I corrected the statement for the case of finite fields $F$.

Comment: I think this would answer the question whether $SL_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to or *larger* than $K_2(\mathbb{Q})$ *if* someone is able to compute $^3(F)$ (or at least compute whether it is trivial or not). Whether or not this is sufficient for @Daniel Sebald is a separate issue -- a comment by him would be nice.